# JavaScript search in JSON by condition

Tags: javascript, json

in json format string i have this structure and data:

```
{
    "Template": [
        {
            "ID": "856",
            "name": "users",
            "Template_Id": 0
        },
        {
            "ID": "857",
            "name": "avatars",
            "Template_Id": 1
        },
        {
            "ID": "858",
            "name": "websites",
            "Template_Id": 2
        }
    ],
    "Fields": [
        {
            "Fields_Id": 0,
            "Template_Id": 0
        },
        {
            "Fields_Id": 1,
            "Template_Id": 1
        },
        {
            "Fields_Id": 2,
            "Template_Id": 2
        }
    ],
    "Field": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "name",
            "Fields_Id": 0
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "lastname",
            "Fields_Id": 0
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "Tel",
            "Fields_Id": 0
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "name": "Email",
            "Fields_Id": 0
        },
        {
            "id": "5",
            "name": "Site",
            "Fields_Id": 0
        },
        {
            "id": "6",
            "name": "Coname",
            "Fields_Id": 1
        },
        {
            "id": "7",
            "name": "MelliCode",
            "Fields_Id": 1
        },
        {
            "id": "8",
            "name": "Tel",
            "Fields_Id": 1
        },
        {
            "id": "9",
            "name": "Email",
            "Fields_Id": 1
        },
        {
            "id": "10",
            "name": "Site",
            "Fields_Id": 1
        },
        {
            "id": "11",
            "name": "Owner",
            "Fields_Id": 2
        },
        {
            "id": "12",
            "name": "address",
            "Fields_Id": 2
        },
        {
            "id": "13",
            "name": "Tel",
            "Fields_Id": 2
        },
        {
            "id": "14",
            "name": "Email",
            "Fields_Id": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

in this structure data i must be create key value array of `Fields` with condistion `Fields.Fields_Id == Field.Fields_Id`, simply that means :

`Fields.Fields_Id[0]` have 5 item as :

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "name",
    "Fields_Id": 0
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "lastname",
    "Fields_Id": 0
},
{
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Tel",
    "Fields_Id": 0
},
{
    "id": "4",
    "name": "Email",
    "Fields_Id": 0
},
{
    "id": "5",
    "name": "Site",
    "Fields_Id": 0
},
```

now i want to get all `Fields` chiled in `Field`,

My Code is below code and that doesn't work correctly:

```
obj = JSON.parse(response.text);
fields_array = [];

var count_fields = obj.Fields.length;
obj.Fields.map(function (fields_item, i) {
    obj.Field.map(function (field_item, i) {
        if (field_item.Fields_Id == fields_item.Fields_Id)
            fields_array[fields_item.Fields_Id] = field_item.id + "|" + field_item.englishname + "|" + field_item.farsiname + "|" + field_item.Fields_Id;
    });
});
```

**UPDATE:**

```
obj.Fields.forEach(function (fitem) {
    obj.Field.forEach(function (ffitem) {
        if(fitem.Fields_Id == ffitem.Fields_Id)
            fields_array[fitem.Fields_Id] = ffitem.id + ":" + ffitem.name + ":" + ":" + ffitem.Fields_Id;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you could achieve expected result like this:

```
obj.Fields.forEach(function (fitem) {
    fields_array[fitem.Fields_Id] = [];
    obj.Field.forEach(function (ffitem) {
        if(fitem.Fields_Id == ffitem.Fields_Id)
            fields_array[fitem.Fields_Id].push(ffitem);                
    });
});
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(fields_array);
```

The result would be:

```
[
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "name",
        "Fields_Id": 0
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "lastname",
        "Fields_Id": 0
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Tel",
        "Fields_Id": 0
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "Email",
        "Fields_Id": 0
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "Site",
        "Fields_Id": 0
    }
],
[
    {
        "id": "6",
        "name": "Coname",
        "Fields_Id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": "7",
        "name": "MelliCode",
        "Fields_Id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": "8",
        "name": "Tel",
        "Fields_Id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": "9",
        "name": "Email",
        "Fields_Id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": "10",
        "name": "Site",
        "Fields_Id": 1
    }
],
[
    {
        "id": "11",
        "name": "Owner",
        "Fields_Id": 2
    },
    {
        "id": "12",
        "name": "address",
        "Fields_Id": 2
    },
    {
        "id": "13",
        "name": "Tel",
        "Fields_Id": 2
    },
    {
        "id": "14",
        "name": "Email",
        "Fields_Id": 2
    }
]
```

]

Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z11etdvL/2/

Comment: Could you please show second line of your code? Does it point to my snippet?

Comment: `Parse error on line 2:
[    [        Object{            
--------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', ']'`

Comment: Ok, can you provide your entire code please? I can`t reproduce the error, it seems like it is from outside. By the way, in what enviroment do you run this code?

Comment: Well, if you validate code snippet provided by me, it will neve pass beacuse it is not a json string. If you validate the result from the concolse it will fail too, because it is not a json string there also. It is a javascript object.  You can transform it into json string by using  JSON.stringify() (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify). Updated my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89241/discussion-between-lazarev-alexandr-and-mahdi-pishguy).